# Can't append <animateTransform> element to SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm attempting to animate certain paths in an SVG file, but I can't seem to append the necessary `<animateTransform>` tag as a child of these paths.

Here's my code:

```
currentState.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var i = 0;

    var map_anim = svgDoc.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animateTransform');
    map_anim.setAttributeNS(null, 'attributeName', 'transform');
    map_anim.setAttributeNS(null, 'attributeType', 'XML');
    map_anim.setAttributeNS(null, 'type', 'scale');
    map_anim.setAttributeNS(null, 'to', '2');
    map_anim.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'freeze');
    var paths = event.currentTarget.children;
    for (i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    paths[i].appendChild(map_anim);
    }
    map_anim.beginElement();
}, true);
```

I've stepped through this code with a debugger and I know that the SVG paths are being accessed as part of the paths array. I can't seem to figure out why `appendChild` won't work, and I haven't been able to find a different method that I can substitute.

Can you please advise me on how to get this animation to work?

Here is the code for the path that is logged to the console after the onclick function runs:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="st12" id="path" d="M165.7,347.4c3.3,0.9,6.4,1.9,9.6,2.6c1.1,0.2,2.3-0.4,3.5-0.6c-0.5-1.2-0.7-2.7-1.5-3.4   c-4.8-4.1-11.8-5.7-18.5-4.2c0.3-1.6,0.6-3,0.7-4.5c0.2-2,0.4-4.1,0.3-6.1c-0.2-2.2-1.4-3.8-3.6-4.6c-3.3-1.2-4.7-3.8-4.6-6.9   c0.1-4.2,1.1-8.4,1.1-12.6c0.1-8.1,0.7-16.2-3.2-23.8c-0.4-0.7-0.1-2.1,0.4-2.9c1.1-1.7,2.5-3.2,3.9-4.7c6.5-7.4,9.3-15.9,8.6-25.6   c0-0.5,0-1,0-1.8c23.4,6.4,46.6,12.7,70.1,19.2c-1,3.3-1.9,6.5-2.9,9.7c-5.5,18.5-11.1,37-16.7,55.4c-0.5,1.7-0.1,2.9,0.8,4.2   c22,32.4,43.9,64.9,65.8,97.3c3.1,4.5,6,9.1,9.2,13.5c0.6,0.9,1.8,1.4,3,1.9c0.4,5.6,1.8,11.2,4.6,16.3c0.2,0.4-0.1,1.5-0.5,2   c-2,2.5-4.1,5-6.3,7.4c-4,4.2-6.8,8.9-8.2,14.5c-0.4,1.5-0.1,3.4,0.4,4.9c1.2,3.3-0.4,8.3-3.6,9.9c-0.6,0.3-1.7,0.3-2.4,0   c-11.7-5.6-24.3-7.7-37.1-8.6c-0.9-0.1-1.7-0.3-2.6-0.3c-1.6,0-2.1-0.8-2.3-2.4c-1.1-8.1-2.6-16-6.8-23.2c-2-3.5-4.7-6.2-8.9-7.1   c-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.9-1.6-1.6c-0.7-1.4-1-3.2-1.9-4.4c-1.1-1.3-2.6-2.9-4.1-3.1c-5.7-0.7-8.2-5-11.3-8.7c-1-1.2-2-2.6-3.4-3.1   c-4.2-1.7-8.6-3-12.9-4.5c-0.9-0.3-1.8-0.7-2.6-1c-2-0.7-2.5-1.8-2-3.9c1.9-6.9,2.3-13.9-0.9-20.6c-1.3-2.8-3.2-5.4-5-8   c-2.7-4-6-7.7-6.8-12.7c-0.3-1.7-0.3-4.1,0.6-5.3c3.7-4.7,2.3-9.5,0.9-14.3c-0.9-3.2-2.2-6.4-3.2-9.6c-0.2-0.7-0.1-1.9,0.3-2.2   c3.5-2.8,3.3-6.2,1.8-9.9c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2C165.5,348.4,165.6,348.2,165.7,347.4z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1">
    </path>
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure that the `appendChild` doesn't work? Or is it just the animation, which is not working?
could you create a fiddle with the corresponding markup?

Comment: I have verified that the animation works if I insert the <animateTransform> tag into the SVG file manually. I can't really create a fiddle because the codebase is pretty large.

Comment: I added the code for the path as it appears after path.appendChild(map_anim) is executed.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't help you without testing/debugging the code myself...
Maybe you can come up with a minimal example setup? Just some markup that is directly related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new element for each path.  If you `appendChild()` an existing element to another parent, it just moves to the new parent.  So the result of your code is that only the last path will end up with the `<animateTransform>`.